# solve congruence for m

Tags: congruences

I just need to know is my calculation here correct. I have

$$ 4m-2 \equiv 1,2,5,6 \pmod{10} $$

and I want to find the value of `m`. Is it correct if I divide 
through by 2, I will have

$$ 2m-1 \equiv \dfrac{1}{2},1,\dfrac{5}{2},3 \pmod{5} $$

Then,

$$2m \equiv \dfrac{1}{2}+1,(1+1),\dfrac{5}{2}+1, (3+1) \pmod{5}$$

And finally,

$$m \equiv 2,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: for m = 0:10 mod(4*m-2,10) end
    ans =  8
    ans =  2
    ans =  6
    ans = 0
    ans =  4
    ans =  8
    ans =  2
    ans =  6
    ans = 0
    ans =  4
    ans =  8

Comment: Hi, shahrina. I notice that you've asked several questions on this site, and the community welcomes your participation. At some point, however, please read the tutorial on [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and start using it in your questions. It is the standard way of formatting mathematical notation on this website, and using it will make your questions easier to read and more likely to get quick answers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @MikeHaskel. I have edited the question.

Comment: @user236182 Thank you. that was  a typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: How do you figure 1/2 +1 =1 or 5/2 +1 =3.  Note 4x3-2=0 not 5 and 4x2-2=6 not 1 ot 2 so clearly you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @fleablood. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $m$ supposed to be an integer? If it is, note that
$$4m-2\ \equiv1,2,5,6\ \pmod{10}$$
means the last digit of $4m-2$ is 1, 2, 5, or 6.* But $4m-2$ is an even number and so its last digit cannot be 1 or 5. Therefore you can eliminate these and just consider
$$4m-2\ \equiv\ 2,6\pmod{10}$$

*If $4m-2$ is negative, its last digit is 9, 8,5, or 4; e.g. $-14\equiv6\pmod{10}$.

Comment: yes $m$ is an integer

Comment: In that case $4m-2\equiv1,5\pmod{10}$ is impossible, so you should just be considering $4m-2\equiv2,6\pmod{10}$.

Comment: So if $4m-2 \equiv 2,6 \pmod{10}$, my concern is how am I to solve for $m$. Is it I can divide through by 2, and obtain $2m-1 \equiv 1,3 \pmod{5}$? And finally get answer as $m \equiv 1,2 \pmod{5}$?

Comment: Sorry, but you can't divide by 2 here. Note that 2*2=4 and also 7*2=4, so 4/2 could be either 2 or 7. Also $2x=3$ had no solutions mod 10. This is because 2 is a 0-divisor. 2*5=0 (and no, you can't divide by 5 either!). Also, when you divide (or multiply) in this sort of equation it doesn't change the modulus. You're doing your math mod 10, and it stays mod 10.

Comment: @ScottBurns You can divide *the whole equation* by 2. $2x\equiv4\pmod{10}$ $\iff$ $2x=4+10k\ (k\in\mathbb Z)$ $\iff$ $x=2+5k$ $\iff$ $x\equiv2\pmod5$. There is nothing in the question that says you have to work only in mod 10.

Comment: @shahrinaismail $m\equiv1,2\pmod5$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks. It has been really helpful.